# Add a Menu Link Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-8

In Drupal 8, I have managed to display a taxonomy vocabularies and their terms as sub-menu.

So, I want to append a menu link [ redirects to the home page and has a home icon ] to the beginning of the menu. How can I add the menu link to the already existing menu?

Answer (score 1):

go to Structure then menu Menus and edit Main navigation menu and you can add what you want from there

Comment: yes that's what I want.  But I also want to show the first link that I added as an icon and the others as just text. Now all are in text